# Nstableview not showing in Objects library

Tags: nstableview

I created a single view application with storyboard using xcode 4.5, and looked for NSTable view in objects library, but could not find it. Before I created a stores board I could see this in the objects library but immediately after the creation of a storeyboard I could find only UITableView. My goal is to create a grid kind of interface. Any pointers on this will be helpful.

Thanks
Sree

Answer (score 0):

NSTableView is for Mac OS X storyboards. UITableView is for iOS storyboards. You probably created the wrong kind of storyboard.

Comment: What is the UI control to use to create a grid view with rows and columns for IOS. UITableView seem to display rows only.

Comment: UICollectionView. See my book to learn more about it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_collection_views